# Core Data with iCloud: how to sync a type of NSManagedObjects only after another type of NSManagedObjects has already synced

Tags: swift, core-data, synchronization, icloud, nsmanagedobject

Good morning,

I'm having an issue with my Swift 1.2 app that uses Core Data with iCloud.

I have 2 custom classes of NSManagedObjects: entity 1 represents Notes and entity 2 represents Projects.
A Note object has a property of only one Project, but a Project can "contain" many Notes.

I have an issue when syncing between different devices via iCloud: when I create a new Project on device 1 and then, immediately, I create multiple Note objects that have that new Project as property, if I'm "lucky" after sync on device 2 I have the exact same data... same new Project containing the same Notes.

Often, though, I'm not lucky with the sync order: **iCloud first syncs some new Notes, but not the Project object that is a property of those Note objects.
In this case, the imported Notes are "orphans" that have no Project assigned (I've checked, the project property in this cases is nil) and are therefore displayed in an unnamed section of the tableView**.

When this happens, I'm kind of ruined: Notes on device 1 are assigned to their Project and on device 2 they are not, and never will.
I have written a method, called after merging the context in `persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges`, that could change the project property of the orphan Notes from nil to another Project, but since my new Project hasn't actually synced on this device, I can't move them there, only in a different Project object.

I don't get it: it looks to me that what I'm trying to do should be very basic usage of Core Data with iCloud sync: *two entities with one to many relationship created on one device that must maintain the same exact relationship after syncing on device 2*. Instead, when I'm not lucky (I keep using this word, because it seems to me that nothing on my part influences the order of syncing nor justifies the reason for some Projects to *never* sync), one of the entities doesn't sync on device 2.

**My question: is there a way to first sync all instances of a particular NSManagedObject (in my case, Projects), and only after that sync is successful sync the other kind of NSManagedObjects (the Notes)?**

Comment: When this happens, does the new `Project` instance ever arrive on other devices?

Comment: @TomHarrington In a few case it did, but usually no, the Projects that don't sync right away, never will... I don't know what I'm doing wrong! Is syncing two connected entities such a fringe use of Core Data with iCloud?

Comment: No, it's a normal use, but that doesn't mean it actually works. Assuming that the `Project` and `Note` entities are saved in the same persistent store file and that iCloud is enabled in both cases, there's no reason for one to sync but not the other.

Comment: @TomHarrington I thought so. iCloud is enabled on both devices and I use the same persistent storage. As a matter of facts, 7 out of 10 new Projects sync immediately and everything is fine. Does the sync order matter? Meaning, if on device 1 I create a new Project first and then a Note of that Project, but on device 2 arrives first the Note and that Note doesn't "find" its Project, could this interrupt the syncing process, causing the Project not to be merged if it arrives "later"? I don't understand, sorry to bother you and thanks for your help!

Comment: @TomHarrington So, it turns out that when a NSManagedObject doesn't sync on device 2 and later I add a new object on device 1, when this new objects gets to device 2 and is actually merged, I have a message in the console complaining about the previous unsynced object: *Unable to find relationship destination object*. My understanding is that the unsynced object actually gets on the device (but I have no trace of it when I log all inserted / updated objects in the notification), but for some reasons it doesn't merge rightaway, and later it can't be merged anymore. Does this make sense at all?

Comment: I just experienced the same issue, and thanks @cdf1982 for making the cause clear! Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: Hi @hyouuu. Sadly no, I've been able to verify the fact that some objects never actually get on the second device, but I have no idea of the reason; actually, I'm not even sure that having multiple entities with relationships is the cause of these objects going awol. I put sync on hold for a moment and I'm working on different parts of my app until WWDC, in the hope that Apple will introduce some improvements to Core Data with iCloud, like they did a couple of years ago. Not a great strategy, I know, but I'm really stuck on iCloud sync... please let me know if you find something!

Comment: Same here... users report data lost after updating the app from time to time, and the syncing issue is very frequent. Tried Ensembles for more than a month but feel it's even worse than Apple's approach. Looks like making our own servers is the only choice, which is not cheap and might be even more error prone... Such a sad situation :(

Comment: @hyouuu I feel you. I really do. Developing my custom sync with a dedicated server is way out of my ability and resources, so the only way for me to have sync in my app, which would really be needed to have a chance of sales, requires a reliable free service. iCloud was the logical solution, CloudKit (which seem to work well, for what I heard) is not an option for me because I need offline data. So, I have to make iCloud work, I'm gonna try again after WWDC, probably developing a simpler app to get the basics working before adding sync to my rather complex app. I'll update here if I have luck!

Comment: Thanks and looking forward to it!

Comment: @hyouuu I just wanted to let you know that I'm having a great experience with Ensembles to manage my Core Data + iCloud sync. [See this answer I gave for details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31346570/3765705)